# Demo for bioinformatics

Tags: bioinformatics

I am a beginner level programmer preparing for the interview in medical research company. Job sounds damn interesting and I would like to get there.
To show my skills and interest, I want to write a program related to the topic.

I think, statistical analysis is quite used in that field, isn't it?
What would you suggest, as idea for demo program? Calculation of basic statistical parameters of input data?

UPDATE: @chl: my background: beginner Silverlight programmer, with basic (college) level of statistics; my intentions: small application, that shows I know Silverlight & I have interest in medical research

@onestop:
company's area of activity: research in proteins, metabolics, central nervous system; job specification: I have just basic requirements, and there is Silverlight knowledge listed

Comment: I don't think there's a single best answer, so this has probably to be made CW. Moreover, I think you need to clarify what you intend to do, and what's your background.

Comment: Not sure this is answerable without a bit more info on the company's area(s) of activity and the job specification. 'Medical research' and 'programmer' are a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a script that aligns short DNA fragments (25-100 basepairs) to an existing genome.

Comment: ...always remembering that you are reinventing the wheel with that: use it as a "proof-of-concept" that you can program, if they want to align short DNA fragments to a genome they would use BLAST.

Comment: @nico, I think @cespinoza implied programing something relevant to the hot topic re-sequencing application (a.k.a. High-Throughput sequencing, Next Generation Sequencing). Blast would not work for that. You want to look at something like [Mosaik](http://bioinformatics.bc.edu/marthlab/Mosaik), [SOAP Aligner](http://soap.genomics.org.cn/soapaligner.html), [ABySS](http://www.bcgsc.ca/platform/bioinfo/software/abyss), [Bowtie](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net), [BWA](http://bio-bwa.sourceforge.net), or [Maq](http://maq.sourceforge.net)

Comment: @Aleksandr: of course I cannot read the mind of cespinoza... but aligning 25bp to an existing genome sounds a lot like checking where some primers bind to the DNA to me... But, again, I may be wrong... I haven't done more than a handful of PCRs in the last few years, and I moved my interests to other fields of biology ;)